# try..catch not working?

Tags: powershell

I have a `try..catch` statement, and its not catching, PS v4.

```
Function ReadFile ([string] $configfile) {
    try {
        [xml]$script:fileInfo = Get-Content $configFile
    } catch {
        Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
```

It never catches, but it errors in the console? Below is the console error:

```
Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\test.xml' because it does not exist.
At C:\test.ps1:3 char:29
+     [xml]$script:fileInfo = Get-Content $configFile
     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\test.xml:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the call to Get-Content so that it stops execution, that way the error can be caught, add **-ErrorAction stop**.

```
Function ReadFile ([string] $configfile)
{
    Try {
            [xml]$script:fileInfo = Get-Content $configFile -ErrorAction stop
    }
    Catch {
            Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
```

Comment: To rephrase: Try-Catch only works with terminating exceptions.

Comment: That worked! Is there any way to set this at the global level for a particular script? Or do I need to specify this every time I call a PS Command? Thanks!

Comment: There are several Scripting Guy articles about this topic, for instance [this one](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/03/08/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-use-erroractionpreference-to-control-cmdlet-handling-of-errors/).